# Why ListBuffer.par foreach does not work?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

In Scala program, I have:

```
var steps : ListBuffer[Step] = new ListBuffer[Step]
var newsteps : ListBuffer[Step] = new ListBuffer[Step]
// why par is not working ?
steps.foreach(step => newsteps ++= step.execute())
```

This works. `step` operates only on internal state, all data is immutable. Yet, when I add `par` to parallelize work:

```
steps.par.foreach(step => newsteps ++= step.execute())
```

the result is not predictable. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListBuffer` is not thread-safe and you are appending it (`newsteps++=`) from multiple threads (that's what happens when you call `foreach` on parallel collection).

Also, Scala discourages mixing side-effects with parallel operation:

> Given the concurrent execution semantics of the parallel collections framework, operations performed on a collection which cause side-effects should generally be avoided, in order to maintain determinism.

http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html

Comment: What would be the scala way for doing this?

Comment: @игор just use `map` instead of `foreach`. Then call `seq` to make result sequential. `val newsteps = steps.par.map(_.execute()).seq`